# rails 4 enabled rails to serve static assets: is it correct? (on heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Environment: heroku

Rails: 4

Ruby: 2

We deployed an app to heroku, and it seemed as though anything in the public folder was not accessible (didn't see the static file so the router kicked in and then complains about no route matching).

To get around this, we set

```
# Rails 4 only flag
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in our production.rb file. Is this really the best way to handle this? Or did we fail to configure the app some how to be hosted on heroku properly?

Comment: It's a good idea to have a CDN vendor to host/serve you static assets, or maybe AWS S3 is another option. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Comment: so would I pre-compile the assets locally and upload those to the as3 bucket? Also, when it compiles the assets, it looks as though it's dropping on some kind of a hashed value onto the end (assume to help with cache killing). Is there a way of handling that so I'm not having to manually updating the static references as I really do enjoy the convenience of saying stylesheet_link_tag "application" vs now I think I will have to set it manually to point to the appropriate css file within the bucket?

Comment: Take a look at this. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31 Looks like asset_sync can help you do the upload job. What I'm trying to say is, it's a good idea not to (or probably never) let you rails process to serve you static stuff, so rails set `serve_static_assets` to false by default for a reason.

Comment: This is great Dean, can you create an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Dean, I used the solution proposed in that link and it worked great.

Answer (score 19):

This is deprecated in Rails 4.2, and it is now an alias slated to be removed in Rails 5.0

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

It should be changed to:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

Comment: And in Rails 5.1: ```config.serve_static_files` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1.
          Please use `config.public_file_server.enabled ```

Comment: xD that's why they say the 2 most difficult tasks of developers are, 1.variable naming and 2.cache invalidations

Answer (score 14):

In previous Rails versions, Heroku injected a plugin that enabled serving of static assets so this issue didn't exist. As this plugin system was removed in Rails 4, they now created a gem which does the same. You enable it in your Gemfile via:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

See [Getting Started with Rails 4.x on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4-getting-started)

You could also of course use a CDN for your assets, but you're not required to.

[For Rails 5+ work on twelve-factor platforms out of the box and the gem is no longer required](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor#rails-5)

Answer (score 10):

As Dean Winchester mentioned it, it is a good idea to use a CDN for your static assets. In fact when using only Heroku your Rails application would have to be responsible to serve static assets since Heroku Cedar architecture **will not** do that for you.

Setting `config.serve_static_assets = true` is the way to go if you don't want to configure a CDN and use only Heroku.

Comment: NB. If your Heroku app is the origin for the CDN (e.g. with CloudFront, as described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn-with-rails), you may still need to have `config.serve_static_assets = true` so the origin can serve the cache misses.

Comment: what does `config.serve_static_assets = true` do? I even don't understand it from the documentation.

Comment: hi thank you for your answer, wouldn't setting `config.serve_static_assets = true` hit the performance of your rails app?

Answer (score 2):

The rails guides are wrong. Try...

```
config.assets.serve_static_files = true
```