# Rails App On Heroku - Status 500 Error => Blank White Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails app on Heroku staging server and everything has gone well except for the error pages aren't working. Every time I get a "status: 500" error, it results in a blank white page, NOT the 500.html static error page.

I have a static 500.html page in the my_app/public folder, and I can access it in heroku if I try to do so directly via myapp.herokuapp.com/500. It will display fine then. But if I get a real "status: 500" error in the program, it will not render the 500.html page... rather, it renders a blank white page.

To create an error, I attempted to go to a non-existent page.
The logs indicate that the "status: 500" error has occured, but again, white page. Here is part of the output from the logs:

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/fakepage" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=20825-b474-4e-37f-c52486140 fwd="67.xxx.xxx.x" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=108ms status=500 bytes=949
Started GET "/fakepage" for xx.xxx.xxx.x at 2014-08-24 03:50:31 +0000
app[web.1]: ** [Raven] User excluded error: #<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/fakepage">
```

In the **config/environment/staging.rb** I have the following:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.serve_static_assets = true  #after the default of false didn't work
```

It seems like this shouldn't be one of those "tough issues"... and not finding any prior posts or articles that directly related to my question makes me think it must be something inane on my part. I'm currently running Ruby 2.0.0p451 & Rails 4.1.1. I have Sentry setup through heroku for monitoring errors. Let me know if there's any other useful info I could provide.

**EDIT**
I should mention that my Gemfile looks like this:

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  ruby '2.0.0'
  gem 'rails' #, '4.1.1'

  gem 'bcrypt'
  gem 'bootstrap_form'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
  gem 'carrierwave'                 
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'dropzonejs-rails'
  gem 'email_validator'             
  gem 'fog'                         
  gem 'geocoder'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'mini_magick'                 
  gem 'paratrooper'                
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'sidekiq'                     
  gem 'sinatra', require: nil       
  gem 'turbolinks'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'unicorn'

  group :production, :staging do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'sentry-raven'
  end
```

That is, I do have the gem 'rails_12factor' in the correct group for both staging & production environments as noted in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550747/rails-4-enabled-rails-to-serve-static-assets-is-it-correct-on-heroku) regarding serving static assets in heroku with Rails4... essentially what an error page would be doing.
I have the app setup to run multiple processes through Unicorn, and have Unicorn temporarily setup to handle Sidekiq processes internally while the app is in testing (to avoid a second dyno). Also running Redis.

**config/environments/staging.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load    = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_assets  = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile  = true #WAS FALSE
  config.assets.digest   = true
  config.assets.version  = '1.0'

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "..." }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :port           => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT'    ],
    :address        => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER'  ],
    :user_name      => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'   ],
    :password       => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => '...',
    :authentication => :plain }

  config.log_level = :info #see everything in the log
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false #per sentry-raven docs
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify #send to registered listeners
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16939069/1466095

Comment: Yes, I believe that is primarily addressing the heroku errors on heroku's end. My issue is with regard to my internal Rails application errors. [The blog](https://coderwall.com/p/w3ghqq) mentions setting up an exceptions_app, but shouldn't Rails be able to serve a simple static status:500 error page in production mode without that? I'm not looking for any custom handling of errors in the Controller - a simple vanilla Rails error page is all.

Comment: No, with heroku Rails doesn't do that. If you set `consider_all_requests_local` to true, then rails will serve an error page.

Comment: Per [This RailsGuide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html), I don't think setting it to `true` in a production environment is a good idea, since it will "cause detailed debugging information to be dumped in the HTTP response, and the Rails::Info controller will show the application runtime context in /rails/info/properties."

Comment: Then your only way is to set up a custom error page in your app for production.

Comment: FYI you're not going to get a 500 internal server error from accessing a non-existent page. You'll get a 404 error instead

Comment: @Sampriti Panda So, I made a basic/generic Rails app, pushed it to heroku, tried to go a non-existent page through the app, and it served me a 404.html error page just fine. That's all I want for my main app, and my simple test app just verified Rails will do that on heroku.

Comment: @Rich Peck  Yes, you're correct, but per the error logs above it served me a status=500, so I went with that. Right now, I'd be happy with a 404 or 500 error page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of the issue. 
The conclusion is that Heroku will serve the basic error pages when a status error (404, 500, etc) happens in a vanilla Rails application without any custom classes. After I determined that, it helped direct the diagnosis.

Looking through the config/environments/staging.rb code, I saw the LOC that sentry-raven stipulated in their docs should be set to false:

```
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false #per sentry-raven docs
```

After setting this back to true, the status error pages started functioning:

```
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true #status error pages work again!
```

So, I may have been misunderstanding sentry-raven's docs & incorporating it incorrectly into the Rails app configs, or something otherwise, but that's what the issue turned out to be. 
So, if you your Heroku hosted Rails app is performing fine and then runs into the "white screen of death" upon any status error, this is one more thing to check in your attempts to diagnose.